# Amazon MWS Boto parsed XML missing values

Tags: python, boto, amazon-mws

Boto 2.40, Python 3.5

When querying Amazon MWS `get_competitive_pricing_for_asin` some values that are present in the raw XML are missing once parsed by Boto.

The raw XML contains the number of offers for each condition in `NumberOfOfferListings`

```
<CompetitivePricing>
    <CompetitivePrices>
      <CompetitivePrice belongsToRequester="false" condition="New" subcondition="New">
        <CompetitivePriceId>1</CompetitivePriceId>
        <Price>
          <LandedPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>18.00</Amount>
          </LandedPrice>
          <ListingPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>18.00</Amount>
          </ListingPrice>
          <Shipping>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>0.00</Amount>
          </Shipping>
        </Price>
      </CompetitivePrice>
      <CompetitivePrice belongsToRequester="false" condition="Used" subcondition="VeryGood">
        <CompetitivePriceId>2</CompetitivePriceId>
        <Price>
          <LandedPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>100.00</Amount>
          </LandedPrice>
          <ListingPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>100.00</Amount>
          </ListingPrice>
          <Shipping>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>0.00</Amount>
          </Shipping>
        </Price>
      </CompetitivePrice>
    </CompetitivePrices>
    <NumberOfOfferListings>
      <OfferListingCount condition="New">109</OfferListingCount>
      <OfferListingCount condition="Collectible">1</OfferListingCount>
      <OfferListingCount condition="Used">51</OfferListingCount>
      <OfferListingCount condition="Any">161</OfferListingCount>
    </NumberOfOfferListings>
  </CompetitivePricing>
```

However only the `Any` value is kept by Boto:

```
    CompetitivePricing{}(
        TradeInValue: None, 
        CompetitivePrices: CompetitivePriceList{}(
            CompetitivePrice: [
                CompetitivePrice{'condition': 'New', 'belongsToRequester': 'false', 'subcondition': 'New'}(
                    CompetitivePriceId: '1', 
                    Price: Price{}(
                        Shipping: USD 0.00, 
                        LandedPrice: USD 18.00, 
                        ListingPrice: USD 18.00
                    )
                ), 
                CompetitivePrice{'condition': 'Used', 'belongsToRequester': 'false', 'subcondition': 'VeryGood'}(
                    CompetitivePriceId: '2', 
                    Price: Price{}(
                        Shipping: USD 0.00, 
                        LandedPrice: USD 100.00, 
                        ListingPrice: USD 100.00
                    )
                )
            ]
        ), 
        NumberOfOfferListings: [''], 
        OfferListingCount: 161{'condition': 'Any'}
    )
```

Note that `NumberOfOfferListings` contains an empty string in the parsed response, and only one `OfferListingCount` from the XML was saved and added as a new attribute.

Does anyone know why the other `OfferListingCount` values are being dropped, or have a good suggestion on how to preserve those values?

I've searched and read the source code: https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/mws/response.py#L520 and can't figure out where it's dropping those values. I have tried this with multiple products and get the same results.

**EDIT:** I've tried playing around with monkey-patching `CompetitivePricing`:

```
class OfferListingCount(ResponseElement):
    pass


CompetitivePricing.NumberOfOfferListings = Element(OfferListingCount=ElementList(OfferListingCount))
```

That gives me a full list of conditions:

```
NumberOfOfferListings: ^NumberOfOfferListings^{}(
    OfferListingCount: [
        OfferListingCount{'condition': 'New'}(), 
        OfferListingCount{'condition': 'Collectible'}(), 
        OfferListingCount{'condition': 'Used'}(), 
        OfferListingCount{'condition': 'Any'}()
    ]
)
```

But without the values.

If I use `SimpleList`:

```
class OfferListingCount(ResponseElement):
    pass


CompetitivePricing.NumberOfOfferListings = Element(OfferListingCount=SimpleList(OfferListingCount))
```

I get the values but not the conditions:

```
NumberOfOfferListings: ^NumberOfOfferListings^{}(
    OfferListingCount: ['109', '1', '54', '164']
)
```

So close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the monkey patch I finally came up with:

```
from boto.mws.response import CompetitivePricing, ElementList, ResponseElement, Element

class OfferListingCount(ResponseElement):
    OfferCount = 0

    def endElement(self, name, value, connection):
        self.OfferCount = value
        super(OfferListingCount, self).endElement(name, value, connection)

CompetitivePricing.NumberOfOfferListings = Element(OfferListingCount=ElementList(OfferListingCount))
```

Which gives me the output I want:

```
CompetitivePricing{}(
    NumberOfOfferListings: ^NumberOfOfferListings^{}(
        OfferListingCount: [
            OfferListingCount{'condition': 'New'}(OfferCount: '105'), 
            OfferListingCount{'condition': 'Collectible'}(OfferCount: '2'), 
            OfferListingCount{'condition': 'Used'}(OfferCount: '58'), 
            OfferListingCount{'condition': 'Any'}(OfferCount: '165')]
    )
)
```

Comment: I like this but where is the output stored? I can't seem to find it.